# netbeans ide coffeescript adding utf-8 bom to output files

Tags: javascript, netbeans, coffeescript, utf, byte-order-mark

I'm using netbeans ide 7.1.1 and running CoffeeScript via node.js to watch my coffeescript folder for changes and then automatically compiling to a different folder with javascript. Everything was working fine and then I don't know what happened but I started getting ï»¿ characters at the beginning of most of my javascript files. It's really frustrating. The only thing that changed was I think I closed the project in netbeans and then reopened it; that's when the problem started. I've checked the encoding to make sure it is set in netbeans as UTF-8. It appears that coffeescript compiler is adding a bom, but i think the actually fault is in netbeans.

I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" for every js file when I run it.

Answer (score 4):

Had exactly the same problem.

Using the 'coffee' script from command line was ok.

Compiling from netbeans garbled all UTF-8 characters.

Solution is simple, but it is amazing how much time must be wasted to find the solution. I don't understand why specifying that our project sources in netbeans are UTF-8 is not sufficient.

So here's the solution, the one that works for me anyway.

Find netbeans.conf in the etc directory of your netbeans installation;

Edit value for **netbeans_default_options**

by adding at the end of the string (before double quote, of course, and with a space before...):

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and voilà. I did this and all is well now.

Oh.. btw, open your editor as an admin otherwise Windows might complain that another program is being used by another program (which is not the case, the directory is just locked)

Comment: what I need For UTF-8 Whitout Bom?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem but I still don't what caused it. Here's what I did:
- opened all .coffee files in notepad++ and changed each one's encoding to UTF-8 Without BOM. Somehow (netbeans?) some of the files turned into UTF-8 With BOM. Problem solved for now.